# How to pass predefined arguments when storing a function

Tags: python, arguments

Is it possible to store a function with predefined arguments to be called by another function?

For example:

```
def function(num):
    print num

trigger=function #store function(1)
trigger()        #prints 1

trigger=function #store function(2)
trigger()        #prints 2
```

trigger calls whatever is stored without passing any arguments. I can change trigger but that would require me to rewrite the function that calls the trigger, so I'm wondering if there is a way to store functions along with arguments when storing a function in a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
>>> import functools
>>> def foo(number):
...     print number
... 
>>> bar = functools.partial(foo, 1)
>>> bar()
1
```

Comment: It looks like you were trying to link the function name, couldn't get it right, and gave up? The key is that the square brackets go outside the backticks. (If you don't like my edit, of course, feel free to undo it.)

Answer (score 2):

Someone already mentioned `functools.partial` which is preferred, but you can also use lambda functions without arguments:

```
trigger1 = lambda: function(1)
trigger2 = lambda: function(2)
```

**Note:** As someone mentioned, be careful about defining functions like this in loops or by referencing any value in the lambda body that might change.

You might end up in a situation like this:

```
a = []
for i in range(5):
    a.append(lambda: i)

b = [func() for func in a]
# equals [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]

# to avoid this, do a.append(lambda i=i: i)
```

Comment: One thing to be careful about here is that this creates a closure, so if you write `i=1` then `trigger1 = lambda: function(i)` instead of `lambda: function(1)`, and `i` later changes, it'll print the new value of `i` instead of `1`. Of course sometimes that's exactly what you want—but when it isn't, you run into one of the most duplicated questions on SO (and an entry in the FAQ).